# Continuous mapping theorem applied to a function with removable discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a sequence of random variables with $X_n \overset {\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} \mu$ and let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous everywhere except at $\mu$. Further assume that the left and right limits at $\mu$ are zero. Now consider a function $h$ which is the continuous extension of $g$, in particular, $h(\mu)=0$. Then by the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) $h(X_n) \overset {\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} h(\mu)$. Does it also follow that $g(X_n) \overset {\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} h(\mu)$ (in analogy with classical limits)?

I arrived at this assertion while reading a proof on the delta method and found [this post,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70050/in-the-proof-of-the-delta-method-about-little-oh-p) which uses the above without proof.

Answer (score 2):

No, this fails if all $X_n$ are the constant $\mu$.

But it will succeed if you assume that $P(X_n = \mu) = 0$ for all $n$ (or even, all but finitely many $n$), since then $g(X_n) = h(X_n)$ a.s.

It's also true if you only assume that $P(X_n = \mu) \to 0$.  For we have $g(X_n) = h(X_n)$ except when $X_n = \mu$, so for any $\epsilon$, by union bound we have
$$P(|g(X_n)| > \epsilon) \le P(|h(X_n)| > \epsilon) + P(X_n = \mu).$$
The first term goes to zero by continuous mapping and the second term goes to zero by assumption.  So we have $g(X_n) \to 0 = h(\mu)$ in probability.

Comment: In the delta method an additional assumption is that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu) \overset {d}{\rightarrow} N(0, \sigma^2)$ from which one gets $X_n\overset {\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} \mu$. I think that this additional assumption can ensure that $P(X_n = \mu) \neq 0$ only for finitely many n but cannot show it rigorously.

Comment: @Holden94: It's possible in this setup that $P(X_n = \mu) \ne 0$ for infinitely many $n$.  (Suppose, for instance, that $X_n$ is a mixture which equals $\mu$ with probability $1/n$ and is $N(\mu, 1/n)$ otherwise.) But I think you should be able to conclude that $P(X_n = \mu) \to 0$ and that should suffice.

Comment: I proceeded in the following way:  $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n =\mu)=\lim_{n \to \infty}P(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)=0)=P(Y=0)=0$, since $Y$ is normally distributed. But still, why can we say that $g(X_n) \overset {\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} h(\mu)$?

Comment: @Holden94: I added the proof of convergence in probability.  You have to be a little careful with your argument: if $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution, it does not necessarily hold that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(Y_n = c) = P(Y=c)$.  (Take for instance $Y=1/n$, $Y=c=0$.)  But it is true that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} P(Y_n = c) \le P(Y=c)$ (portmanteau theorem) and that is sufficient here.